# why after the last update on ionic 3 it give an error on json() method?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have **a provider service contain** this code which give me an error on `json()` method:

```
getCategorys(){
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    return this.http.get("http://localhost/Test1/getCity.php?action=getcategory",{headers: headers}).map(res => res.json()); 
}
```

but when I run the code it tell me that there is an error:

> property 'json' doesn't exist in type 'Response'

What is the issue in this code? why is it an error? What is the solution? (note: that it happened after I install the latest version of ionic).

My TypeScript code where I call the provider is as follows:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.recipesProvider.getCategorys().subscribe(
      data =>{
        this.categorys = data.categorys
        console.log(this.categorys)
      } ,
      error =>{
        //console.log(error);

      } 
    )
}
```

And the html code is:

```
<ion-content padding class="card-background-page">
    <ion-list [virtualScroll]="categorys">
       <ion-item *virtualItem="let cat" no-lines> 
        <ion-card (click)="showRecipes(cat.id , cat.name)">
            <img class="card-img" [src]="cat.image"/>
            <div class="card-title"><span class="card-title-cat">{{cat.name}}</span></div>
            <div class="card-subtitle">41 Listings</div>
        </ion-card> 
        </ion-item>
   </ion-list> 

</ion-content>
```

those implementation return to me a cities information 
it return the value as a json .. in previous 2 months I were coding with no such error .. but after the last update of ionic 3 it then put a red line under json() method .. and if I cut this method from the code it will not return anything .. I want to put another method or syntax to solve this issue(**retreive same data from database** .. but with another method which don't show to me an error in type **Response**) and to protect the project validation

this is my provider code which have the error at json() method =>

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http , Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class RecipesProvider {



  constructor(public http: Http , public httpClient : HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello RecipesProvider Provider');

  }

  getRecipes(idCity: number) {
    var headers = new Headers();
   headers.append('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  return this.http.get("http://localhost/Test1/getCity.php?action=getrecipes&idCity="+idCity,{headers: headers}).map(res => res.json());
  }


  getCategorys(){
    var headers = new Headers();
   headers.append('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

   return this.http.get("http://localhost/Test1/getCity.php?action=getcategory",{headers: headers}).map(res => res.json());
  }

  getDetails(idCategoryD : number){
    var headers = new Headers();
   headers.append('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
   return this.http.get("http://localhost/Test1/getCity.php?action=getDetails&idCategoryD="+idCategoryD ,{headers: headers}).map(res => res.json());

  }
}
```

Comment: where is there any php involved? I remove the php tag.

Comment: In my issue , is it necessary to involved the php code to solve the problem ? :/ , I don't think so

Comment: any one can help please , for my graduation project :/

Comment: Please add more information to your question: 
1. Please edit and add package.json
2. You are using "http" or "HttpClient"?

Comment: I edited it .. and as shown I am using "http"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for updating your question.

[Http module](https://angular.io/api/http/Http) is now deprecated, I suggest to use [HttpClient](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient) instead.

Easiest fix for your problem is to remove the **map** operator like so:

```
 return this.http.get("http://localhost/Test1/getCity.php?action=getrecipes&idCity="+idCity,{headers: headers});
```

And call the method as before:

```
this.recipesProvider.getCategorys().subscribe(
  data => {
    this.categorys = data.categorys
    console.log(this.categorys)
  },
  error =>{
    //console.log(error);
  } 
)
```

More you can have a look into [pipeable operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md) which allows you more control on the data received.

Comment: Thanks bro .. I change it and use the HttpClient and its done correctly